# Excel Compare two cells in one sheet to two in another, copy a certain range of cells if they are equal

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this is a stupid question(I searched and couldn't find a answer.) I was trying to find out if this was possible with functions but it seems like I will need to use a macro, I don't have any experience with them but can learn.

I am trying to compare 2 cells in sheet 1, Resource name and project code(C and L) against two of the same named columns in sheet 2(where they are A and D). The Resource name is formatted like: Lanier, Joe so its last name comma space first name. Project code is a mix of letters and numbers with no spaces. If they are the same, I would like to copy a range of cells in sheet 1(T through Y) into the matching row's columns X through AC in sheet 2. It would overwrite any data in those cells.

If it is also possible, if there was a way to highlight the cells or rows that don't have a match that would be such a great help so my boss would know what he needed to manually copy over. Thanks so much!

EDIT: Included below macro that seems like it should work but isn't. It is highlighting all of the cells. Any idea what could be changed?

Sub ertert()

```
Dim i&, j&, s$, col As New Collection
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        s = .Cells(i, 1) & "~" & .Cells(i, 3)
        If IsEmpty(.Item(s)) Then col.Add i, s
    Next i
End With
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Columns(1).Interior.Color = xlNone
    For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        s = .Cells(i, 3) & "~" & .Cells(i, 12)
        If IsEmpty(col.Item(s)) Then
            .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            j = col.Item(s)
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 5).Resize(, 6).Value = .Cells(i, 24).Resize(, 6).Value
        End If
    Next i
End With: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

edited July 23 - 10:30EST

no VBA or macro needed you can use simple formulas and some copy and paste

on sheet2, at the end of the data columns, create a new column (AD?) with this formula

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,[book1]sheet1!$C$4:$C$14,1,FALSE),"")<>"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D4,[book1]sheet1!$L$4:$L$14,1,FALSE),"")<>""),[book1]sheet1!T4,X4)
```

and copy it over the next 6 rows (AD to AI)

I assumed the first row being 4 and the formula is searching 10 rows in sheet 1, adjust as needed then copy down to last of your data rows

if you have a match, the sheet1 data will be displayed otherwise, sheet2 data will be there

copy this chunk, go to X4 and use EDIT - PASTE SPECIAL - VALUES if excel 2003 or click the PASTE button on upper left and choose PASTE VALUES if Excel 2007+

I recommend you get information on `VLOOKUP` to better understand this solution

cheers

Comment: They are on different workbooks(sorry for the mixup!) would this solution still work? Trying to make the process as simple for my boss as well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just tried it out, this doesn't seem like it goes through the whole sheet(should have I specified that). It has to go through all of the data in worksheet 1 to compare to the values in worksheet 2 to see if there is a match. That is why I figured it had to be a macro using loops.

Comment: to refer to a different workbook, change cell references to [Book1]Sheet2!, 'Book1' being the name of said book

Comment: I edited my post to include a macro that seems like it should work, but is isn't, it is just highlighting all of the cells. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that if that row doesn't have a match, it needs to be manually entered from sheet 2 into sheet 1, so there has to be a way to highlight the ones that don't have matches. Thanks for the help.